# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. Already saw questions with the same error, but nothing helped

Tags: flutter, dart

so, i've been working on a CRUD on flutter, and this error got me pretty bad
I'm totally new to dart..
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

```dart
        class UserForm extends StatelessWidget {
        
          final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
          final Map<String, String> _formData = {};
         
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Formulário de Usuário"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                  onPressed: () {
                    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
        
                    if(isValid) {
                    _form.currentState!.save();

                    Provider.of<Users>(context, listen: false).put(User(
                      id: _formData['id'],
                      nome: _formData['nome'],
                      email: _formData['email'],
                      avatarUrl: _formData['avatarUrl'],
```

The error occurs on this last bit of the code.
I deleted some parts of the code that I thought It doesn't have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Have you read [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these

**a)**

```dart
_formData['id']!
```

`!` operator forces null value.

---

**b)**

```dart
_formData['id'] ?? ""
```

`??` is the shortcut for

```dart
_formData['id'] != null ? _formData['id'] : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this
ex)
_formData['id'] ?? ''